# How to inject a service into an attribute to lookup roles in DB

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I'm setting up a new way of authenticating using Azure AD (AAD), but role based authorization still needs to be retrieved from a legacy system.
The AAD authentication is in place and that works like a charm. The token also includes a claim, lets call it `userid` for the sake of argument.

What I want to create is am Attribute that can contact the legacy system, without disregarding the default implementations for AAD token verification.

I was able to create the following attribute, which I can use on my methods with `[LegacyRole("MyRole", "MyOtherRole")]` while still having `[Authorize]` on my class that handles the token correctly, so far so good:

```
public class LegacyRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private string[] _roles;
    private ILegacyRoleService _service;
    public LegacyRoleAttribute(params string[] roles) : base()
    {
        _roles = roles;
        _service = new LegacyRoleService(); //This instantiation, I want to get rid off.
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        string userID = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "userid").Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
        if (!_service.HasAnyRole(userID, _roles))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to inject the service properly, instead of using a new statement in the construction. Off course I do not want to change the format of the attribute, so nothing like `[LegacyRole(serviceInstance,"MyRole", "MyOtherRole")]` or so.

Any way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiation of LegacyRoleService() method then please declare its class(where the method is decclared) as [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

For Example,

```
Public Static LegacyRoleServiceclass()
```

Comment: I properly want to inject the service, not just create a singeton instance, giving the consuming app control of which sevice dependency to use in the attribute.

Comment: Then instead of creating the separate method LegacyRoleService() write the code directly inside LegacyRoleAttribute

Comment: Think you're missing the goal here. I want to inject a service into the attribute, so not tying it to a particular service (that should be done by the startup class of the main application) and definitely not copying code that has nothing to do with the attribute itself, whose only task is to receive the request data and use it to invoke an yet to be defined service.

Comment: Please try using an interface.

Comment: ILegacyRoleService is an interface and LegacyRoleService uses it. I want LegacyRoleService (or any other class based in the ILegacyRoleService interface ) to be injected into the attribute, so it doesn't need to be coupled to the library that holds the service.